# What's the etymology of the word "zilch"?

Tags: etymology

What's the origin of the word "zilch" and how it came to mean nothing?

Comment: OED says "origin uncertain", and (unlike many other entries where they say that) they don't even give any *possible* etymologies. I'd guess (wildly) it's Yiddish/German. From 1958 - [In POW lingo, they got zilch](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XmAIAQAAMAAJ&q=%22got+zilch%22&dq=%22got+zilch%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eifjULvBLuG60QW6sYDoCQ&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA)

Comment: @FF So is my guess but wanted to be sure.

Comment: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=zilch&searchmode=none), anyone?

Comment: @user: If it's not even credible enough for OED to advance it as a possibility, I don't think you've got much chance of "making sure" here!

Comment: General reference: even though the reliable references say "origin uncertain", that is in fact the answer to the OP's question.

Comment: A few minutes in [Google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=b-EDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA74&dq=rescue+zilch&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uDHjUKHtDI6F0QHsxYD4CQ&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=rescue%20zilch&f=false) finds a 1956 attestation, which seems earlier than either OED or etymonline.

Comment: If it comes from Yiddish/German, what would the original Yiddish/German word be?

Comment: @Peter Shor: I didn't mean I thought it was *actually* a Yiddish word used by German Jews - if that had been the case presumably OED would have identified the original without any real problems. I just meant the *sound* of it seems to me to be consistent with it having been coined by Yiddish speakers.

Comment: @PeterShor: You should send the 1956 antedating to the [OED](http://public.oed.com/the-oed-today/contribute-to-the-oed/) and email to [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com), plus the info in your answer.

Comment: I second Hugo !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This website](http://www.abc.net.au/newsradio/txt/s1973580.htm) says

> Robert Hendrickson says “zilch” goes back to the 1920s when the name
>   “Joe Zilch” was used to mean “a good for nothing college boy” –
>   someone who was a waste of space.

Looking through Google books, “Joe Zilch” certainly seems to have been used in that way. It would be quite a coincidence if these two usages of "zilch" were unrelated. And unless someone can find an early attestation for "zilch" meaning "nothing",  it would appear that "Joe Zilch" came first.

From [1925](http://books.google.com/books?id=iwfiAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Joe+Zilch%22&dq=%22Joe+Zilch%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PUHjUPy_OKfp0AGu54DIBw&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAg):

> Such men as Joe Zilch, Joe Mulch, Joe Collitch, Samuel Hall, and Others have been members of this Paternity. ... Said to be Very Exclusive, absolutely refusing to take in others than Protestants, Catholics, Jews, Negroes, Mohamadens, S. C. A's, Westerners, and Round Table boys.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon the post and decided to post quick update from Etymonline:

**zilch (n.)** 
    "nothing," 1957; "insignificant person," 1933, from use of Zilch as a generic comical-sounding surname for an insignificant person (especially Joe Zilch). There was a Mr. Zilch (1931), comic character in the magazine "Ballyhoo," and the use perhaps originated c. 1922 in U.S. college or theater slang. Probably a nonsense syllable, suggestive of the end of the alphabet, but Zilch is an actual German surname of Slavic origin.

> The [Cadence] agency aims to have each album cover actually promote
>   the record, on the theory that "the day of pretty, boffy, zoomy and
>   zingy covers for the sake of zilch is no more." ["Billboard," Oct. 28,
>   1957]

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=zilch

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it was from Yiddish-German, from the Slavic side.  I think it may have originated from that useless cure all, zhelch, which is Slavic for  bile.

Comment: Hello Thomas.  This is potentially a very good answer.  Could you provide a reference?  That is always helpful to provide good answers.

Answer (score 0):

The predecessor expression, "Joe Zilch," a placeholder name for a generic or insignificant person, appears to have been derived from the Vaudeville act of a comedian named Frank Tinney.  A man named Joseph Zilch was married to Ida May Chadwick, who performed on stage with Tinney.  Tinney used the name to refer to characters in his bits who were mentioned but did not appear on stage.  His first use of the name may have been in 1918, although the earliest contemporary reference to the name in print is from 1922.

> But the high peak of the evening is when [Tinney] comes on with Marion
> Sunshine and sings the sad romance of “The Coachman and the Widow.”
> This sweet ballad has a rather involved scenario about a widow who is
> driving away from the burial services of her husband (the late Joseph
> Zilch) when, in the coachman she recognizes an old sweetheart of hers.

New York Times, August 27, 1922, section 6 (Drama, Music, Fashion), page 1.

The practice of using that name was picked up by newspaper columnists.  Nunnally Johnson, who later wrote the screenplay to the Dirty Dozen, used the name as early as 1923.  The entertainment reporter, Walter Winchell, wrote a column entitled "The Diary of Joe Zilch," as early as 1926. The humor magazine famously used the last-name Zilch for a variety of characters beginning in 1931.

In a 1932 column, Walter Winchell attributed the name to Tinney, and explained how it started.

> Wonder if Ida May Chadwick’s husband has any legal right to halt the
> joshing of his real name – which is Joe Zilch?  Funny how that
> clowning began.  Ida was part of a show in which Frank Tinney starred
> and the Zilchs honeymooned with the troupe.  And one dull matinee
> Tinney found the audience very difficult to amuse – and for want of
> something funnier to say to cover up a flop quip – he spied the groom
> sitting in a box and exclaimed: “Ah! My friend Joe Zilch is with us!”
> . . . This enticed a wow response, they say . . And the comedian ‘kept
> it in” – getting roars with the name wherever he appeared . . . Today
> the tag is among the glorified with one humor magazine [(presumably
> Ballyhoo)] cashing in most heavily with it.

Nevada State Journal (Reno), April 22, 1932, page 4.

"Zilch" standing alone, with its current meaning, is attested as early as 1954.

> The latest okay slang word among sports in the Maryland Air National
> Guard is “zilch,” which means “nothing.”

The Evening Sun (Baltimore), July 5, 1954, page 27.

I posted a more thorough look at the [origin of "Joe Zilch" and "zilch" on my Early Sports 'N Pop-Culture History Blog](https://esnpc.blogspot.com/2021/08/frank-tinney-ida-may-chadwick-and.html).

[[Nancy Friedman posted a follow-up piece focused on "zilch" as a trade name for various products](https://nancyfriedman.typepad.com/away_with_words/2021/08/word-of-the-week-zilch.html)][2](https://nancyfriedman.typepad.com/away_with_words/2021/08/word-of-the-week-zilch.html).  Her post includes a good summary of my findings, and includes the definition of "zilch" from the Dictionary of American Slang (1960, revised edition 1967):

> A completely dull, ineffectual, unattractive or insignificant person.